# Why does Linq ToList<string> return System.Data.DataRow?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

When using the below code it works fine to return a var that is filled with DataRows I can loop:

```
var GetSetRows = Order.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Job_No"))
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(g => g.First());
```

but what I would like to do is return a `List<string>` instead.

I tried:

```
List<string> c_strLSetTitle = Order.AsEnumerable()
                                   .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Job_No"))
                                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                   .Select(g => g.First().ToString()).ToList();
```

but this returns a list filled with elements that say `System.Data.DataRow`, but it does return the correct amount, i.e. that amount of items that I am expecting to be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g.First()` returns object of type `DataRow`. Then you are calling `ToString()` which returns the type name `System.Data.DataRow`. At the end you have a list of type names.

If you want to select a particular column, then project group of rows into value of some field of (first) row:

```
g.First().Field<string>("FieldName")
```

Or you can use grouping key if you want to return values of `Job_No` filed:

```
List<string> c_strLSetTitle = Order.AsEnumerable()
                                   .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Job_No"))
                                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                   .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

That will return values of duplicated `Job_No` fields.

Answer (score 2):

Because `g` is a collection of `DataRow` objects, so

```
.Select(g => g.First().ToString())
```

returns a collection of the string `System.Data.DataRow`

If you want to extract a *field* from each datarow, then use:

```
.Select(g => g.First().Field<{type}>("{fieldname}").ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<string> c_strLSetTitle = Order.AsEnumerable()
                                     .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Job_No"))
                                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                    .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```